# any tool to track a specific visitor to the site?

Tags: web, analytics

Let's say that if I want to track John, I send John an email telling him to access mywebsite.com/description. He actually accesses mywebsite.com but I now that if description is added it must me John as there is no description page. Is there anything like this?

As far as I know Google analytics does't offer such a product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) can resolve your purpose. Soem feature of AWStats are:-

A full log analysis enables AWStats to show you the following information:

- Number of visits, and number of `unique visitors`,
- Visits duration and last visits,
- Authenticated users, and last authenticated visits,
- Days of week and rush hours (pages, hits, KB for each hour and day of week),
- Domains/countries of hosts visitors (pages, hits, KB, 269 domains/countries detected, GeoIp detection),
- Hosts list, last visits and unresolved IP addresses list,
- Most viewed, entry and exit pages,
- Files type,
- Web compression statistics (for mod_gzip or mod_deflate),
- OS used (pages, hits, KB for each OS, 35 OS detected),
- Browsers used (pages, hits, KB for each browser, each version (Web, Wap, Media browsers: 97 browsers, more than 450 if using browsers_phone.pm library file),
- Visits of robots (319 robots detected),
- Worms attacks (5 worm's families),
- Search engines, keyphrases and keywords used to find your site (The 115 most famous search engines are detected like yahoo, google, altavista, etc...),
- HTTP errors (Page Not Found with last referrer, ...),
- Other personalized reports based on url, url parameters, referer field for miscellanous/marketing purpose,
- Number of times your site is "added to favourites bookmarks".
- Screen size (need to add some HTML tags in index page).
- Ratio of Browsers with support of: Java, Flash, RealG2 reader, Quicktime reader, WMA reader, PDF reader (need to add some HTML tags in index page).
- Cluster report for load balanced servers ratio.